# Targetting Windows 8.1 with Windows 10 SDK in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

we currently build our C++ Code with Visual Studio 2017 and we were required to have our binaries run on Windows 7 as well until only recently.

Hence our settings in C++ projects for the Windows SDK version to be used is "8.1" and by defining _WIN32_WINNT=0x601 as a preprocessor macro, we target Windows 7 as a platform, as recommended at various places by Microsoft.

Now we want to add ARM64 as a new platform, but this requires the Windows SDK version to be set to 10.0.10240.0 and since the Windows SDK Version to be used is a project global setting, this would affect the existing other platforms we build for (Win32 and x64) as well.

Now if we set the Windows SDK version from 8.1 to 10.0.10240.0 (or later versions), would we lose the ability to run our code on Windows 8.1, as long as we use _WIN32_WINNT=0x602 (for targetting Windows 8.1)?

Comment: No, the only role of `_WIN32_WINNT` is to stop you from accidentally using a winapi function that is only available on Win10.  Even if you do, you'll quickly find out when you test it on a 8.1 machine.  Do look at the feasibility of targeting arm64, these kind of machines are invariably locked-down and only accept programs from the store.

Comment: *"the Windows SDK Version to be used is a project global setting"* - No, it's a per-configuration setting. Nothing keeps you from choosing a different value for your ARM64 targets and all other targets.

Comment: @IInspectable: If I show the project properties of one of my projects in VS2017 and if I change the value of "Windows SDK version" for, say, "All Configurations" and Platform "x64", the value is changed as well for the current other target, "Win32" (which is x86). The same behaviour is to be observed for ARM64. If I change this value, the value "<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>" in the "<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">" is changed in the vcxproj file. Setting the SDK version to be used on a per Configuration or on a per platform level would be wonderful. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @HansPassant: I think you are right for Windows RT, but not for Windows 10 or Windows 11 on Arm64.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. You should be *C/C++* -> *Preprocessor* -> *Preprocessor Definitions*.

Comment: @IInspectable: This is the place where I define Preprocessor Macros like _WIN32_WINNT and other stuff. I cannot see at this location in Visual Studio where I could enter the Windows SDK to be used, can you clarify? The global setting I was writing about is to be found at "General ->Windows SDK version".

Comment: You are conflating two concepts: Your minimum target version (which is what you set through the `_WIN32_WINNT` preprocessor symbol) and the SDK version. The SDK version is of little relevance. As long as it is no older than your minimum target OS, you can use it.

Comment: @IInspectable: That has always been my understanding from the last 25+ years of Win32 programming. What got me stumped is the official recommendation to use the 8.1 SDK for targetting Windows 7, as if using Windows 10 SDKs for targetting Windows 7 or 8.1 would create problems.

Comment: @Stefan Kuhr : This [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f11530a-d7a0-4c50-aeaa-094d054402b8/can-i-target-windows-7-while-using-sdk-100150630?forum=vcgeneral) might help you. You need to check the supported platforms of the sdk.

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943334/newer-windows-sdks-cause-api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2-dll-missing-on-windows-7-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Minxin Yu is the answer to this question. [This discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f11530a-d7a0-4c50-aeaa-094d054402b8/can-i-target-windows-7-while-using-sdk-100150630?forum=vcgeneral)
points to the [Windows SDK page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)  that clearly states that the current Win10 SDK allows for targetting Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8.1.