# Newer Windows SDKs cause api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2.dll missing on Windows 7/8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, windows-7

I'm compiling my Visual C++ executable for Windows 7 on Windows 11 with the preprocessor definition `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` which should give me Windows 7 backwards compatibility. Also I'm using the Windows SDK `10.0 (latest installed version)`. However, when I run the executable on Windows 7, the DLL `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2.dll` is not found. Upon further inspection, the executable wants to use the [`AreFileApisANSI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-arefileapisansi) function from that particular DLL. Strangely, when searching for this DLL on Windows 11, it is not found either but the executable works fine. Compiling with or without static C Runtime (CRT) does not help. Windows 8.1 users also have this problem. Using an older Platform Toolset also did not work (e.g. Visual Studio 2019 instead of Visual Studio 2022).

**However, finally I found a working solution.** Setting the Windows SDK Version to `10.17763.0` produces a working executable for Windows 7, the newer SDK versions do not. How can this be explained? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? [The latest Windows SDK supposedly supports Windows 7 SP1 still](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk) so why does it still cause this DLL problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have reported this problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Newer-Windows-SDKs-cause-api-ms-win-core/1583505).

Comment: The issue on dev community was closed as "irrelevant" (MS-style). Any other response from VS support on that?